# A lot of poorly formatted C code lately

Tags: discussion, questions

Lately I have seen a lot of strangely formatted code:

Instead of this:

```
// some
// code
```

we see this:

`

```
// some
// code
```

`

because the asker puts two extra back ticks around his code block.

Has anything changed in the SO user interface that favors this practice?

Comment: I've seen it too. Maybe someone went to see the Wizard? I think it should say if the question was asked with the Wizard or not.

Comment: @Lundin yes, checking the timeline of a question will say "created from wizard" and checking the edit history will show "Created from Ask question wizard" on the first revision. But I've found it's no longer needed to check these. Literally all the instances of this misformatting I've seen came from the wizard. I stopped checking at some point as it became clear it's just a useless task.

Comment: In all honesty, I feel like the quality of questions from users *using* the wizard has been worse than prior to its graduation.

Comment: @Larnu no wonder, the wizard is full of bugs.

Comment: Without warning, the wizard walks by... :)

Comment: @Lundin but this one doesn't turn tears into joy. I'm not happy when the wizard walks by.

Comment: The notorious Stacks Editor strikes again.